# Question about Lipschitz Inequality for Multivariate Vector Functions: Metric Selection

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Lipschitz Continuity Defintion:
Given two metric spaces $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$, where $d_X$ denotes the metric on the set $X$ and $d_Y$ is the metric on set $Y$, a function $f:X \to Y$ is called Lipschitz continuous if there exists a real constant $K \geq 0$ such that, for all $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $X$,

$d_Y (f(x_1),f(x_2))\leq Kd_X(x_1,x_2)$

Let's say that I want to bound $\Vert f(x_1,x_2)-f(\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2)\Vert _2$ with the Lipschitz ineqaulity, where the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is Lipschitz, and the Euclidian norm is denoted by $\Vert\cdot\Vert _2$. So following the above inequality I get $$\Vert f(x_1,x_2)-f(\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2)\Vert _2\leq K\Vert (x_1,x_2)-(\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2)\Vert _m,$$ where $\Vert\cdot\Vert _m$ denotes the metric for $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^2$, but I am unsure of what metric to use? Do I use the Frobenious norm, or something else? Is this open to choice? If so, how do I choose? What are the rules? I can really use some clarity on this. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the pair $(x_1,x_2)$? Why can't you write it as a concatenated vector $[x_1^T, x_2^T]^T$? In this case, you can just use the Euclidean norm.

Comment: @unobservable_node I think that may solve my problem, I will need to think more about it in the greater context of my problem. But for the sake my curiosity, let's assume $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Am I free to select the norm?

Comment: The function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined in such a way that $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I think the metric on the right-hand side of the Lipschitz inequality should be the same as the one on the left-hand side. I remember the Lipschitz inequality in the case of a control system $\dot{x}=f(x,u)$, where $\|f(x_1,u)-f(x_2,u)\|_2\leq K \|x_1-x_2\|_2$. I hope this helps!